# Django Has to Keep Updating The Backed Updated Info

Tags: python, django

I need technical advice about Django and I have no idea where to even look for the general direction.

Right now, I have an app that keeps track of work/shift schedule. It is an Android/iOS app with a Django backend and I am the backend engineer. When a user updates their schedule and makes a backup to our server, the phone sends a long sequence of requests. This sequence starts with 'backup' URI and ends with 'vacationData' URI. When the backup is successful, the last request my server will receive will be the 'vacationData' URI. What I am trying to achieve is this: just like in Google Spreadsheet, whenever the user updates their schedule and make a backup, the "shared schedule" URI has to update accordingly. I began setting up the "share schedule" URI with Django Signals that listens to the "vacationData" URI. However, now I realize that the only user sends GET request to "shared schedule" URI and thus the shared timetable won't be updated unless the user chooses to send a new GET request to "shared schedule". Is there any way to send the updated(newly backed up) schedule info to the client regardless of whether they requested it or not? When I think about the Google Spreadsheet, it's not like my computer is constantly sending GET requests to the Google server every 0.5 seconds, but I still get to see what others are doing in real-time. So what kind of technology should I implement in this case? What does the big-picture architecture look like in the server side?

Thanks a lot, and have a great rest of the week!

P.S.: I didn't know where else to ask such a general question since I have no mentor. I know that the StackOverflow community prefers very specific technical questions. If I need some mentoring about where I should look for what I want to achieve, or if I have a very general question about development, what community is the best for this?

Comment: You could look into websockets, push notifications etc. This is not site to do any recommendations of of-site resources as it is off-topic, more over your question generally is too broad

Comment: I agree that it is too broad for StackOverflow.... which is why I am asking where to post such a broad question in my P.S. part. Where would you recommend for such a broad question?

Comment: As I already stated recommendations are off topic -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. 
If you do enough research you would probably soon get your answers ( read some books, tutorials etc. )

Comment: got it ) maybe I should look into more books

Answer (score 0):

You *can* implement a client-side script that sends a `GET` request every few seconds to pull the latest data from the backend. In fact, based on the use case you described this may be the simplest solution - assuming clients have a stable internet connection.

However, if you're looking for a more sophisticated solution that will serve you better in the long run you are probably looking for web-socket technology. Luckily Django has a package, `django-channels` to do just that:

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/